# Keeping same session, 1 single browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

The title of the question may be irrelevant to what I am trying to find out. My goal is to write a test that will

A) login to Hotmail

B) Delete the junk mail in my junk folder.

Design wise I have created 2 separate test classes.  `TestSignInPage1.class` is only testing the user login part which is working and passed.

`TestJunkFolderDelete.class` will go to junk mail folder and do the deletion. I understand I simply can’t use the junk delete test on its own, a user 1st needs to login to the account so I called the `TestSignInPage1` class in the junk folder.

```
@Test
    public void testJunk(){
//The part below will get my login credential from TestSignPage class
        TestSignInPage1 t= new TestSignInPage1();
        t.testPage1();
//The following part will handle junk folder clean operation
        WebDriver driver=br.openBrowser("firefox", "https://outlook.live.com/owa/?realm=hotmail.com&path=/mail/junkemail");
        JunkMail jm= PageFactory.initElements(driver, JunkMail.class);
        jm.doJunkClean();
```

**Problem:** Once the login part has been executed, the junk folder delete test opens up another new browser and again asks for login information.

**Question:** In professional world how would you tackle this (i.e.: you will have 1 test only, is there a way to keep the same session 1 browser) etc?

Comment: Why do you write that as two separate tests in the first place? It seems you just want a simple command line app. Open a browser, do the login with that browser, then delete the junk mail with that same browser. If you really want to keep two tests, then open a browser from the test method, then delegate to a method taking the browser as argument. And delegate to that same method from the second test, to make sure only one browser is opened.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your approach. "Why write 2 separate tests"- I read somewhere that each page needs to have it's own test and I thought in professional world may be that's how someone would write it.

Comment: When you're writing tests, sure. But you're not writing a test. A test is used when you want to check that a web application that you wrote, most of the time) behaves the way it should behaves. What you seem to be doing is an application allowing to automate the task of deleting the junk mail in your hotmail account. So there's no reason to write that as tests. You can use the selenium API in any context other than tests, even if that's where it's often being used. I for example use it in a command-line app used to download my github invoices. It's not a test. It's an app.